# Слайдер товаров с выделением центрального slick

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

Как сделать такой слайдер с помощью slick slider или может другой какой

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

пробовал так, но все ровно не получается так сделать, как на фото

```
$('.data_hit__slader').slick({
  centerMode: true,
  centerPadding: '40px',
  slidesToShow: 3,
  arrows: false,
  responsive: [
    {
      breakpoint: 768,
      settings: {
        arrows: false,
        centerMode: true,
        centerPadding: '40px',
        slidesToShow: 3
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 480,
      settings: {
        arrows: false,
        centerMode: true,
        centerPadding: '40px',
        slidesToShow: 1
      }
    }
  ]
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.hit-product {
    background-color: #282828;
    padding: 80px 0;
}

.stitle {
    font-family: 'ReformaGroteskDemiC';
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 48px;
    line-height: 22px;
    color: #fff;
}

.data_hit__slader {
    overflow: hidden;
}

h3 {
    margin-top: 0;
    padding-top: 10px;
}

.item {
    max-width: 100%;
    flex-basis: 100%;
    min-width: 400px;
    background-color: transparent;
    margin-left: 90px;
    margin-right: 90px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 4%;
}

.data-img::before {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}

.slick-center .data-img::before {
    content: none;
}

.data-img {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
    .item {
        margin-left: 10px;
        margin-right: 10px;
        min-width: 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Page test</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">
<script src="https://fastcdn.org/jQuery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Add the slick-theme.css if you want default styling -->

</head>

  <body>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
<div class="hit-product">
      <div class="container">
        <p class="stitle">Абсолютные хиты продаж</p>
      </div>
      <div class="hit__slider">
        <div class="data_hit__slader">
          <div class="item">
            <div class="data-img" style="background-image: url(https://www.1zoom.ru/big2/595/334196-svetik.jpg);">
              <div class="data-info">
                <div class="hit-header">
                  <h3>Проект дома 7*9</h3>
                  <span class="size">86 м<sup>2</sup></span>
                </div>
                <p class="price">641 037 р.</p>
                <a href="" class="btn-white">Подробнее</a>    
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <div class="data-img" style="background-image: url(https://www.1zoom.ru/big2/595/334196-svetik.jpg);">
              <div class="data-info">
                <div class="hit-header">
                  <h3>Проект дома 7*9</h3>
                  <span class="size">86 м<sup>2</sup></span>
                </div>
                <p class="price">641 037 р.</p>
                <a href="" class="btn-white">Подробнее</a>    
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <div class="data-img" style="background-image: url(https://www.1zoom.ru/big2/595/334196-svetik.jpg);">
              <div class="data-info">
                <div class="hit-header">
                  <h3>Проект дома 7*9</h3>
                  <span class="size">86 м<sup>2</sup></span>
                </div>
                <p class="price">641 037 р.</p>
                <a href="" class="btn-white">Подробнее</a>    
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <div class="data-img" style="background-image: url(https://www.1zoom.ru/big2/595/334196-svetik.jpg);">
              <div class="data-info">
                <div class="hit-header">
                  <h3>Проект дома 7*9</h3>
                  <span class="size">86 м<sup>2</sup></span>
                </div>
                <p class="price">641 037 р.</p>
                <a href="" class="btn-white">Подробнее</a>    
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
 


  <script type="text/javascript">
   $('.data_hit__slader').slick({
  centerMode: true,
  centerPadding: '25%',
  slidesToShow: 1,
  arrows: true,
  responsive: [
    {
      breakpoint: 768,
      settings: {
        arrows: false,
        centerMode: true,
        centerPadding: '20px',
        slidesToShow: 1
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 480,
      settings: {
        arrows: false,
          centerPadding: '5px',
        slidesToShow: 1
      }
    }
  ]
});
  </script>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: стрелки думаю сам доделаешь ) и на брекпоинтах моб. раставишь как нужно, десктоп как на картинке